# Probability of 5 events not happening

Tags: probability

Im not very good at math so i figured i would ask here. I have a series of events, 5 events to be exact. Each event happens in succession(aka event 2 only fires if event 1 doesnt happen) and i was wondering what was the probability of not having all 5 events fire.

Event 1: 3/10 chance
Event 2: 3/20 chance
Event 3: 1/10 chance
Event 4: 1/20 chance
Event 5: 1/4 chance

Context: im running a decades challenge in the sims 4 and im trying to see if the chance of getting to adulthood is correct for the era im starting it. The event chances are the odds of death for that lifestage.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: so continuing your logic - does Event 3 happen only if 1 and 2 have not happened, or only if 2 has not happened?

Comment: Yes each event only happens if the previous events dont because if the event is triggered that person dies thus being unable to trigger the following events

Comment: "event 2 only fires if event 1 doesn't happen" seems to suggest you cannot have "all 5 events fire"

Comment: That is kind of the point if an event fires that is death, im specifically asking what is the probability of all 5 events not happening

Comment: You can make yourself a probability tree diagram.  Frustratingly, you gave the probabilities as chance things *do* happen, and we wanted to talk about things *not* happening, so just subtract each from $1$.  To move along a particular branch of the probability tree, you simply multiply together the probabilities of each section of the branch you are traveling along... here that would be $7/10 \times 17/20\times 9/10\times 19/20\times 3/4$

Comment: I did the multiplying and it came out to 0.38154375 or for convince 0.38 roughly. In my research i did it seems that the rate of death before 20 was about 30% of the population. Im gonna need to tweak my numbers it seems. Thank you for the help i didnt know what to do and this was a big help.